# Powershell: Filtering unwanted values from get-wmiobject win32_product

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to get the list of installed applications on a machine into a Listbox and so far I have this:

```
function programsinstalled_current
{
$prog = get-wmiobject win32_product -computer summer -Property Name | select Name
foreach($program in $prog)
{
[Void]$program_list_current.items.add($program)
}
}
```

and it returns this in the list box:

[image]

My question is how do I get rid of the unwanted '@{name=' at the start of each program name and the '}' at the end of each name?

I've tried the below code with getting the AD groups of a machine into Listbox and it works fine, but the same syntax won't work the `get-wmiobject win32_product`:

```
function fill_current_list
{
$processnames_t = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $current_hostname.text -Property MemberOf).MemberOf 
foreach ($processname in $processnames_t)
{
[void]$AD_list_current.Items.Add($processname)
}
```

If possible, I'd rather not use `-replace`

Thanks

Comment: FYI [one should never use `Win32_Product`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575378/powershell-for-software-inventory/71576041#71576041) since it can result in unexpected changes even when only querying the class. Instead, query the registry directly as explained in my linked answer above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
[Void]$program_list_current.items.add($program.name)
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. I've been trying all weekend to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: $program is a PScustomObject created by select-object. $program got a property named Name. IT's the property that you need! Not the pscustomobject. Hope I was clear :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also add all product names without looping on them:

```
$prog = gwmi win32_product -computer summer -Property Name | select -expand Name
$program_list_current.items.AddRange($prog)
```