# PowerShell for Software Inventory

Tags: powershell

I would like to know how to have two columns containing the software installed and name of the PC:

```
$Path = "C:\Gabriel"
$LogPath = "C:\Gabriel"
Select Name,Directory,@{Name="Outlook";Expression={(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | where vendor -eq Outlook)}},
                      @{Name='Desktop';Expression={(Get-wmiobject win32_computersystem)}} | Export-Csv C:\Gabriel\Outlook.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, along with properly formatting your post? Not quite sure I understand.

Comment: They want a column with the computer name and a column with installed software. The code sample supports this albeit confusingly since it contains other irrelevant operations.

Answer (score 6):

First, [**Win32_Product** is cancer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697046/584676). Despite the name implying it's a read-only operation **it will silently execute repair installations for any software failing an integrity check**. Avoid using it because:

1. This can introduce unintended and unscheduled change in a controlled environment; **and**
2. It is unacceptable for a read-only operation to result in a changed state; **and**
3. Even if it doesn't cause an outage due to re-installation, the integrity check can be CPU and disk intensive as can the re-installation of software, causing resource contention with other applications running on the system.

MS has previously stated this is a "won't fix" issue. Since it's how the class has behaved for so long, "fixing" it could break folks who do rely on the erroneous behavior today.

---

By repurposing some of the code in my linked answer above we can instead **check the registry for the software inventory**, get the current computer name, and return a `[hashtable]` with the computer name as the key and its value being an array of installed software on the system:

```
# We need to check for both 64-bit and 32-bit software
$regPaths = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
  "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

# Get the name of all installed software registered in the registry
$softwareInventory = @{
 $env:ComputerName = $regPaths | Foreach-Object {
    ( Get-ItemProperty "${_}\*" DisplayName -EA SilentlyContinue ).DisplayName
  }
}
```

> **Note**: This will not capture software not installed using Microsoft Installer, but most software is installed via MSIs (often `.exe` installers simply wrap around `.msi` installers).

`$softwareInventory` is now a hashtable with the computer name as the key. So once this is collected from a server/computer, you can reference the software inventory of a computer named `PlanetExpressServer01` like so:

```
$softwareInventory['PlanetExpressServer01']

# OR (must still wrap property name in quotes for specially parsed characters
# such as the hyphen (-)

$softwareInventory.PlanetExpressServer01
$softwareInventory.'PlanetExpressServer-02'
```

---

If you instead want the computer name to be its own property, not the key of a `hashtable`, we can make one more adjustment when creating `$softwareInventory`:

```
$softwareInventory = [PSCustomObject]@{
  ComputerName = $env:ComputerName
  Software = $regPaths | Foreach-Object {
    ( Get-ItemProperty "${_}\*" DisplayName -EA SilentlyContinue ).DisplayName
  }
}
```

Simply create a new `hashtable` key called `ComputerName`, assign the `$env:ComputerName` to it, put the software inventory under a new key called `Software`, and cast the hashtable to a `PSCustomObject` so it operates more like a conventional object than an array. Now each "row" will have both a `ComputerName` "column" and `Software` "column".

---

### Additional Information

For additional information on why **Win32_Product* is bad, the following article is a good read, and offers additional techniques to avoid its use:

[Please Stop Using Win32_Product To Find Installed Software](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/)

Thanks to @FoxDeploy for the link from a now-deleted question.

Comment: This be enshrined as the perfect answer to this question, so that when someone asks it again tomorrow, we can just point them here.

Comment: Thanks for that article on the now-deleted duplicate of this question, I've added it to the answer as additional reading.